# Array with random positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, html-lists

I have a problem with random positions. I make a script that set `<li>` random on the page. You can see it here: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/5L9FN/4/)

But the problem is. That the items overlap. I want make this script with a array. I would like an array with fixed positions. There are always 8 items. And these eight items, all have one fixed position.

How can I make this? How can I make a array with fix positions?

Here my code:

```
var images = [];

function init() {
    $('.friend-selection li > div').each(function(){

        var id = this.id;
        var img = $('#img_' + id);
        var randomTop = 400*Math.random(); //random top position
        var randomLeft = 500*Math.random()+1; //random left position

        $("#parent_" + id).css({ //apply the position to parent divs
            top     : randomTop,
            left    : randomLeft
        });
    });
};

init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a set of 8 fixed, non-overlapping positions that you'd like to use randomly and uniquely:

```
var images = [];

// Constructor for the "Position" structure
function Position(left, top) {
    this.left=left;
    this.top=top;
}

// sortFunction routine to help randomize array
function rand(ar){
    return 0.5-Math.random();
}

// Array containing the 8 positions you want to use
var positionArray = [
      new Position(0,  0) 
    , new Position(50, 50) 
    , new Position(100,100) 
    , new Position(150,150) 
    , new Position(200,200) 
    , new Position(250,250) 
    , new Position(300,300) 
    , new Position(350,350) 
];

function init() {
    $('.friend-selection li > div').each(function(){

        var id = this.id;
        var img = $('#img_' + id);
        var imageIndex = parseInt(id.substring(id.length - 1)); // This is a hack because you're using "picture*" as the id

        $("#parent_" + id).css({ //apply the position to parent divs
            top     : positionArray[imageIndex].top,
            left    : positionArray[imageIndex].left
        });
    });
};


// Randomize array - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802661
positionArray.sort(rand);

init();
```

Comment: Yeah this i what i looking for. But there is a bug in the script. I dont know where it is. The last item get nog a position. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/5L9FN/5/

Comment: The bug is because your pictures start at `1` but the array index starts at `0`. Change the line that look like: `var imageIndex = parseInt(id.substring(id.length - 1))` to `var imageIndex = parseInt(id.substring(id.length - 1))-1;`

Answer (score 0):

Put the items in sequence in the array so that you cannot overwrite the already filled positions and use Shuffle to shuffle the array in a random order.

But as there is no such function in Javascript you will have write one on your own. Something like this would work.

```
shuffle = function(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};


alert(shuffle([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uxnn7/